# What would be the alternative to fix "Access forbidden 404" on my test site while using basic_authentication module for rest resource?

Tags: 8

Background:
I had http authentication enabled by htaccess on my test site. I had created REST resource using Drupal 8 core REST web services modules and views. When i used authentication as `basic_auth` than on Test site  got `access forbidden 404` for each page request. Uninstall `basic_authentication` make it work but i want basic_authentication should work for my test site. What would be the better alternative for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can send in the user and password parameters with your API call.

```
user:password@http://site-url.tld
```

this way you can still communicate with the app whilst keeping it behind basic auth